# What does the $\;\bigcup\;$ symbol mean, as in $\;\bigcup_{j=1}^NI_j\;$?

Tags: calculus, notation

What does the $\;\bigcup\;$ symbol mean here?

$$\bigcup_{j=1}^NI_j$$

Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: It means union.

Comment: see wiki entry of [set union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).

Comment: It's the symbol for the [union of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) and can be written in Latex or MathJax with the `\bigcup` command.

Answer (score 1):

As others have written in comments, $\bigcup$ is the symbol of the union of sets. Precisely,

$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^N I_j = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \dots \cup I_N
$$

Note the similarity with the summation notation

$$\sum_{j=1}^N a_j=a_1+a_2+\dots a_N$$

More generally, if $A$ is a nonempty set,

$$
x\in \bigcup_{j\in A} I_j \text{ if and only if there exists }j\in A\text{ such that }x\in I_j 
$$

There is a similar notation for intersection: $\bigcap_{j=1}^N$.